# Android SlidingDrawer handler's image

Tags: android, image, handle, slidingdrawer

I'd like to use my own image as handler's image.

[image]

How can i change the default handler image to onther image?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ImageView` with `src` pointing to your image as the handle:

```
<SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"

     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"
         android:src="@drawable/my_image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

     ....

</SlidingDrawer>
```

You will probably want to convert that image to a 9patch so it can be stretched to fill the height of the window.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a selector for the slider button so that you can have different images for different states(focussed,non focussed etc...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedpressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbutton" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding background image to the SlidingDrawer's button.